# replacing list of objects with object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a list of objects such as below:

```
let list = [
    {key:'x', date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    {key:'y', date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    {key:'z', date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];
```

and the object of Differences for reading such as below:

```
{x:30, y:50, z:60 }
```

I want to have a result as below:

```
[
    {key:'x', date: '12/1/2011', reading: 30, id: 20055 },
    {key:'y', date: '13/1/2011', reading: 50, id: 20053 },
    {key:'z', date: '14/1/2011', reading: 60, id: 45652 }
];
```

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. Stack Overflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Kindly post some of your efforts/code then only we can help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```js
let list = [
    {key:'x', date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    {key:'y', date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    {key:'z', date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];

let obj = {x:30, y:50, z:60 }

list.forEach(i => i.reading = obj[i.key])

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do with map

```js
let list = [
    {key:'x', date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    {key:'y', date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    {key:'z', date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];

let obj = {x:30, y:50, z:60 }

list.map((item)=>{item.reading=obj[item.key]; return item})

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
let list = [
    {key:'x', date: '12/1/2011', reading: 3, id: 20055 },
    {key:'y', date: '13/1/2011', reading: 5, id: 20053 },
    {key:'z', date: '14/1/2011', reading: 6, id: 45652 }
];

const obj = {x:30, y:50, z:60 }


/* [
    {key:'x', date: '12/1/2011', reading: 30, id: 20055 },
    {key:'y', date: '13/1/2011', reading: 50, id: 20053 },
    {key:'z', date: '14/1/2011', reading: 60, id: 45652 }
]; */

const objKeys = Object.keys(obj)


list.forEach(item => {
 objKeys.forEach(key => {
   if(key === item.key) {
     item.reading = obj[key]
    }
  })
})

console.log(list)
```

Answer (score -2):

```
const diff = {x:30, y:50, z:60 }
const res = list.map(obj=>{
    obj.reading = diff[obj.key]
    return obj
})
```

Comment: Please explain your answer in a few words if possible